# Why isn't image disposed by GC

Tags: c#, opencv, garbage-collection

I am getting frames from OpenCV Emgu in c# and I run out of memory after a while. The problem disappears when I manually dispose the old frame. This seams to only happen when I get the frames from Emgu. If I get frames from AForge for instance it gets cleaned up as expected.

Since I make a copy of the data in CopyToNewBPP and dispose the frame from the capture the memory in unmanaged should be released. And there should be no references to the old frame when I set a new bitmap in the picturebox.

Question is what am I missing in my understanding.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Capture capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.0.89:554/live2.sdp");

        Task t = new Task(() =>
        {
            DateTime last = DateTime.Now;
            while (true)
            {
                var frame = capture.QueryFrame();
                if (frame == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = CopyToNewBPP((Bitmap)frame.Bitmap);
                frame.Dispose();

                pictureBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    var old = pictureBox1.Image;
                    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
                    if (old != null)
                    {
                        old.Dispose(); // this should be done automatically by GC in my mind
                    }
                }));
                frame.Dispose();
            }
        });
        t.Start();
    }

    public Bitmap CopyToNewBPP(Bitmap orig, PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    {
        Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(orig.Width, orig.Height, format);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(orig, new Rectangle(0, 0, clone.Width, clone.Height));
        }
        return clone;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like I figured this out myself. The problem is I get frames so fast I fill up memory before GC are scheduled to run. Adding GC.Collect(); to the loop will keep memory usage down, but will ofcource use the Dispose method as that is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer maybe help

Image Gui program is important that memory lick.

e.g code.

```
if(pictureBox.Image != null)
{
   pictureBox.Image.Dispose();
   pictureBox.Image = null;
   pictureBox.Image = [New Image];
}
```

Comment: That is somewhat what I have, the "problem" is that GC should dispose the image on its own since there are no references to it anymore